# CMake INCLUDE_DIRS variable doesn't contain the right path

Tags: cmake, eigen3

I have a project that I'm trying to compile on a Linux-based HPC system using CMake. The project relies on the Eigen3 package, so I specified the path to the Eigen3 config file in the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable as below (an excerpt from my CMakeLists.txt file).

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/gpfs/loomis/apps/avx/software/Eigen/3.3.7")
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
message(STATUS ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Note: the directory @ `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` contains the installation tree `/share/eigen3/cmake`, where the config file is located. The `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` also contains an `/include` directory. So `find_package` shouldn't have any difficulty retrieving Eigen3's location, from my understanding.

However, the result of the `message` command is:

```
-- /gpfs/loomis/apps/avx/software/Eigen/3.3.7//gpfs/loomis/apps/avx/software/Eigen/3.3.7/include
```

not `/gpfs/loomis/apps/avx/software/Eigen/3.3.7/include` as desired. So `include_directories` isn't actually passing the correct package path. How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Blind guess: the installation is broken, probably `INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR` was set to the absolute path instead of a relative path when Eigen was configured and installed. Anyway, the modern way would be to use `target_link_libraries(my_target eigen)`. Maybe that works with that installation.

Comment: This could be [Issue #1990](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1990) which has been fixed in [a967fadb](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/commit/a967fadb21c17622c6cdec13ad9c827054624eb4) (master) and in [1b080fdc](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/commit/1b080fdcb96455cdfa0f955cc7f24f7e51da0639) (3.3).